# Android AutoCompleteTextView with data from a web service, problems displaying the suggestion list

Tags: android, web-services, autocomplete, android-asynctask

a problem that I can't manage to resolve it.

**What I want to achive:**
Display suggestions in a AutoCompleteTextView comming from a web service call. The final result should look like this:

[image]

**What I did so far:**

In my layout I have an AutoCompleteTextView like this

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAutoSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

On my Activity I have this:

```
 autoCompleteAdapter = new AdapterAutoComplete(context, ????? what should I have here?????, null);
         autoCompleteAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
         txtAutoSearch.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
            txtAutoSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                private boolean shouldAutoComplete = true;

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    shouldAutoComplete = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (shouldAutoComplete) {
                       new GetAutoSuggestionsTask().execute(s.toString());
                    }
                }

            });
```

The AsyncTask is pretty simple, `onPostExecute` I set the adapter with the data returned from the webservice

```
autoCompleteAdapter = new AdapterAutoComplete(context, ????? what should I have here?????,result);
txtAutoSearch.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
```

The adapter looks like this:

```
public class AdapterAutoComplete  extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<Person> lstPersons;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public AdapterAutoComplete(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, List<Person> lst) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, lst);
        activity = a;
        lstPersons = lst;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return lstPersons.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public Person getCurrentPerson(int position) {
        return lstPersons.get(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        lstPersons.remove(position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtProfession;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item, null);
            Utils.overrideFonts(activity, vi);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.txtProfession = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtProfession);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        Person o = lstPersons.get(position);

        if (o.name != null) {
            holder.txtName.setText(o.name);
        } else {
            holder.txtName.setText("N/A");
        }

        if (o.profession != null) {
            holder.txtProfession.setText(o.profession);
        } else {
            holder.txtProfession.setText("N/A");
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**What actual happens:**

- the web service returns the list I need, so data is available
- in Adapter the getView doesn't seem to execute so I guess there is something wrong done in it.
- there is no suggestion list displayed with my values
- I have no idea what I need for Adapter constructor, for textViewResourceId. 
  What am I doing wrong? I am stuck please help.

Answer (score 7):

After a quick scan through of the documentation it looks like your on the right track.

You need to have you async request to get a list of results from an external source. Autocomplete should be rechecked on each key press (cancelling the previous request for data), this should be fired using `addTextChangedListener` which is what you're doing. So far so good.

From this list of results you need to construct and fill an Adapter: You're custom adapter should extend ListAdapter & Filterable (as described in [setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setAdapter(T)) documentation).

Once you have an adapter it should be as simple as calling:

```
// AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Remember that any UI changes should be done on the UI Thread or using a Handler.

getView() should be called when the adapter has:

- Changed with setAdapter()
- `.notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called on the ListView.

If the above two events don't cause new `getView()`s.You should ensure the methods `getCount()` and `getItem()` are returning the correct values.